# Remote server browser

Tags: linux, command-line, nerdtree

Is there any tool for pretty display directory structure where I'm currently in?

My flow is pretty tedious like

```
cd 'dir1'
ls
cd 'child1'
ls
```

and so on. I'd like to have some NerdTree + console next to it opened in current directory. Is there any way do to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question:
A very basic overview of the recursive contents of the current directory can be found with `find`:

```
mtak@frisbee:~/Documents/vagrant$ find .
.
./.vagrant
./.vagrant/machines
./.vagrant/machines/default
./.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox
./precise32
./precise32/Vagrantfile
./BuildRaring
./BuildRaring/Vagrantfile
./BuildRaring/.vagrant
./BuildRaring/.vagrant/machines
./BuildRaring/.vagrant/machines/default
./BuildRaring/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox
./BuildRaring/bootstrap.sh
```

It's not NERDTree, but it's a start. You could also take a look at [Midnight Commander](https://www.midnight-commander.org/):
[image: MC screenshot]